# How to insert all the nested dictionary values in the SQL table in a single row

Tags: python, python-3.x

Writing the Nested Dictionaries in SQL Table. Code is getting written.

Since I'm dealing with nested dictionaries. So Main Dicionary (User_ID value) is getting writted one row and other Nested Dictionary values are getting written in another row..

I want to write all the values in the single row.

Let me know any suggestions to write the values in single row.

Code - Output( User-defined Values)

```
{'1101': {'Name': 'Test_User', 'Age': Test_Age, 'Occupation': 'Test_Occupation'}}
```

I want to write all these nested dictionary values in the single row in SQL table.

SQL Output (For Example)

```
User_ID  User_name    User_Age    User_Occupation

1101     Test_User    Test_Age    Test_Occupation
```

Thanks for your time in Advance !!

What I have tried:

Part of code use to write the values into SQL Table :

```
for k,v in user_details.items():
    user_col = k
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Details (User_ID) VALUES ("%s")' % (user_col))

    cols = v.keys()
    vals = v.values()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
    ', '.join(cols),
    ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));

    cursor.execute(sql, list(vals))
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
for k,v in user_details.items():
    columns = ", ".join(["User_ID"] + list(v.keys()))
    values = ", ".join([k] + list(v.values()))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(columns, values))
```

Comment: If I execute your code, " sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found " error is show. So I've modified your code. But in that also I'm facing error like ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dsf' in 'field list' .                                           Seeking your help to sort out the Issue.

Comment: I've reposted in Stackoverflow. Please find this from this mentioned link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330009/error-unknown-column-dsf-in-field-list-while-trying-to-insert-nested-dic

Comment: Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You could update `values` dict with `USER_ID` field and use only second query.

```
v['User_ID']=k
```